# java swing paint transaction

Tags: java, swing

I have a matrix of JToggleButton as components of a JPanel.
I want to call setSelected() for a group of those buttons
but I want the changes to be visually simultaneous.
How can I achieve this?

Consider the following code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class Main {
    private static final JToggleButton buttons[][] = new JToggleButton[8][8];

    public static void main(String args[]){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(8, 8, 0, 0));

                //Initialize buttons and add them to panel
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j){
                        buttons[i][j] = new JToggleButton(){
                            public JToggleButton setRowAndColumn(int row, int column){
                                addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                                        onClick(row, column);
                                    }
                                });

                                return this;
                            }
                        }.setRowAndColumn(i, j);

                        buttons[i][j].setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(40, 40));
                        panel.add(buttons[i][j]);
                    }
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    //This method is called when the JToggleButton at [row][column] is clicked 
    private static void onClick(int row, int column){

        //In this example all other buttons at the same row or column
        //as the clicked one, are also selected

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
            buttons[i][column].setSelected(true);
            buttons[row][i].setSelected(true);
            //I don't want to see visual changes yet
        }

        //All changes should be visualized now
    }
}
```

Basically I want onClick to be executed as a transaction (visually).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain in more detail to any of us ignorant (me). What do you mean by "transaction" here? Please explain in greater detail what this code is doing that you don't want it to do, and what it's not doing that it should be doing.

Comment: `public class Main` Please give classes a meaningful name. I have dozens of classes (originally) called `Main` in my test code package and it is a pain to rename very new one. Something like `TestImmediateToggleButtonSelect` would be good for this.. It is not 'good programming in that it includes a verb, but that does not matter so much for a test class.

Comment: Side note: don't use a MouseListener on objects derived from AbstractButton. Better to use ActionListener or ItemListener or a ChangeListener on the ButtonModel.

Comment: *"I want the changes to be visually simultaneous"* Here, they **are** visually  simultaneous! I.E. click any button, and (to the naked eye) it seems the entire row and column becomes selected instantly. If that's not what you meant then explain further, as mentioned by @HovercraftFullOfEels. Also agree with not using a `MouseListener`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, @AndrewThompson.
However the changes are not really simultaneous.
I can see the buttons changing one after another.
Maybe your computer is very fast.

Comment: *"I can see the buttons changing one after another."* ..wow. I'm not sure what combination of hardware and eyesight would make that possible! Perhaps you should just accept that for most it will be instantaneous and move on to other parts of the app. There is possibly a hack that would fix it, but it would require custom painting the 'button grid' and writing code to implement the functionality of the existing buttons. I really don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: `I want onClick to be executed as a transaction (visually).` - this is what happens. As you execute your loop the setSelected() property of each component is changed and the component invokes repaint() on itself. The repaint() request is handled by the RepaintManager so that all requests are done at one time to make painting more efficient. The components will only be repainted AFTER the loop has finished executing

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, @camickr.
Curiously (to me) a call to panel.repaint() after the loop solved my problem.